# Angular can not read property in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using angular-media-player module from https://github.com/mrgamer/angular-media-player
And I wrote my html as follows

```
<audio media-player="audioControl" data-playlist="list" a="{{audioControl.ended}}">
```

I can read attribute a when property audioControl.ended changed. But in my controller I attempt

```
console.log($scope.audioControl.ended);
```

and it failed.

But it is confusing that I can use its methods in controller like this

```
$scope.audioControl.play();
```

Anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "failed" ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write it     TypeError: Cannot read property 'ended' of undefined

Comment: Then you're trying to access it before it gets its value, therefore `audioControl` is undefined. Does it get its value from an ajax response or something?

Comment: Yes you are quite right ! When I use setTimeout to access value later it works fine . I do not use ajax . By the way , is it possible to know when the directive is ready ?

Comment: You probably just need to initialize `$scope.audioControl = {}` in your controller so it wouldn't break.

Comment: If the directive initializes your value, then it will always happen after your controller initializes since that's the first thing that happens. That's why I suggest to initialize the variable.

Comment: Learned from your answer. It helps with $scope.audioControl.property , but unfortunately still I got problem when $scope.audioControl.method()

Comment: Yes, because the `method()` would be undefined as well :) The better thing to fix is your design, since it looks like you're immediately trying to use those in the controller. Therefore, you should probably not wait until the directive to assign the value. Or don't use it at that stage at the controller.

Comment: Thanks for your advice . If I find any solution I will discuss with you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to know what's going on. 
When I use

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log($scope.audioControl.ended);
}, 3000);
```

Then it wouldn't throw en error. It looks like that the directive isn't ready when I try to use it , so , any way to detect the directive is ready?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-if` for your directive. As like

```
<audio ng-if="audioControl.ended" media-player="audioControl" data-playlist="list" a="{{audioControl.ended}}">
```